# Alert when a question on a meta gets upvoted?

Tags: stack-exchange

I know this isn't very important and all and is a really weird request but here it goes but is it possible for someone to write me up a type of script that can do this and can preferably....

1. Choose which meta sites on stackexchange to receive alerts for
2. and also give me a friendly reminder as to when my question gets upvoted (in meta)

Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: All of your questions on a given Meta or only specific ones? -- Also for (specific) questions from other users?